# Shared project in server AOS generate error

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

In Dynamics AX 2012 Development mode when I try to open shared project 75% of time I have this error :

> xPropertySetData::unpack : Property not found : 2880

When I press "OK", dynamics AX is closed. I'm not working with my local AOS. We connect to the AOS on a server.

I have seen this error in other sites and no one has a solution to the issue.

[image: xPropertySetData::unpack : Property not found : 2880]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're a `System administrator` in AX (to rule out problems with privileges)?

Did you try clearing the usage data (Tools > Options > User data > Reset)?

Did you try removing the [AUC](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php/Object_caching) file from your application data folder?

Did you try recompiling the application?

Are Ax32Serv.exe and Ax32.exe of the same version?

Did you try restarting the AOS('s)?

Do you have only one AOS in that environment? If not, do you have the same problem when you connect to another AOS?

**P.S.** And of course, if the problem is only with one project, why not delete it and create a new one with the same objects?

Comment: we have restarted the AOS but nothing better, we have so much AOS but the problem is with AOS server where we work.
and the AX32.exe is the same in other workstation and he don't have the problem.

Comment: Please try all the other suggestions. Is the problem only with one user opening one project? Is it possible to delete the project and create an identical one?

Comment: I just experienced the same issue while working on an AX project. Some people on my team had the same issue, others didn't. In the end we found the solution, the AX version on the server had the CUMUL 3 update installed but the clients we use on our laptops didn't have the update. This is why we had those errors. Bottom line: UPDATE YOUR LOCAL AX CLIENT SO IT MATCHES THE ONE IN THE SERVER! :)

Comment: It's great that you've been able to identify the root cause of this issue. It's true that the versions of the client and the server must *always* match.

Answer (score 2):

Did this code originate from AX 2009?  I'm trying to interpret the error, and the `xPropertySetData::unpack` sounds like a traditional pack/unpack and the property 2880 isn't matching up to the expected variable.

Right click the project itself (don't open) and click properties, and try re-setting each property.  If it's named "myproject", re-type it so that it will re-pack that new variable in.

This makes me think if you can export it, you might be able to import and AX 2012 can handle the up-converting.

In AX 2009, I believe properties are referenced by name, and not by Id, which it appears to be in this case.  I don't have a 2012 environment, but check \Macros\Properties and see if that index is in there and if that gives you any clue.

Modify this job and see if it can help you find any more information and examine the objects in question.

```
static void Job67(Args _args)
{
    ProjectNode customProject;
    str temp;
    TreeNode    node;
    ;

    customProject   = infoLog.projectRootNode().AOTfindChild('Shared').AOTfindChild('YourProjectHere');
    node            = TreeNode::findNode(@'\Data dictionary\Tables\CustTable');

    temp = customProject.AOTgetProperties(true, true);
    info(temp);

    temp = node.AOTgetProperties(true, true);
    info(temp);
}
```

Comment: thx alex. your solution get me more competence but it not résolut my problem :(